# Html/CSS: image taking half screen with mouseover and link

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create a page like this one from Armani Brands. Their site came up with many different links but all I want to do is a full page divided into two like the Screenshout below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhn8H.jpg

It would have the mouseover effect and each would link to a different url.

Thanks!

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real StackOverflow question, as you aren't asking a very specific question, but here it goes anyway:

Okay so you take an element and give it two child elements that will be your large images. `float: left` them. Looks like the one on the left is slightly smaller than the one on the right so give them widths like `width: 45%` for the left one and `width: 55%` for the one on the right. Set their background images to the images you would like and then set `background-size: cover` so the images take up the entire element. `background-position: 50% 50%` to centre the BG images.

This should help you get started. In the future, ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** after checking out the [Armani page](http://www.armani.com/ca/brandpage_section) (that you DID NOT link to in your question) I realized that you are probably asking specifically about the hover event.

I built something very similar to this on Codepen so this should be able to answer your question:

http://codepen.io/hi_mynameisdave/pen/EaWrOJ

Essentially it's a `<div>` with a child `<div>` that's hidden until the parent is hovered over.